# Library version indicated in Maven pom is not being used

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly-10

I have 3 projects, **MyLibA**->**MyLibB**->**MainProject** in that dependency order, straightforward and simple enough.

I want to use the latest version of `javax.mail` so I put the following code in **MyLibB**'s `pom.xml`, and wrote some mail code in **MyLibB**.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, for some reason it ended up using `1.5.5`, because another dependency (Wildfly) in **MyLibA** has `1.5.5` included:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

The funny thing is, when I went to look at the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab in **MyLibB**'s and **MainProject**'s `pom.xml`, it resolves to using `1.6.1`, which is not the case when I am running the project! I know because the debug says `DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5`.
I have also encounter this before in the past with projects running in Wildfly 8 (broken) but worked in Wildfly 10.

What gives? How can I fix this besides updating the Wildfly version?

Comment: Is it possible to exclude the mail dependency from the Wildfly dependency definition? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: Yes I actually tried that, but it didn't worked so I thought I had done something wrong. I'm thinking this is because it exists at the Wildfly project folder level, so it didn't work.. 
This was what I had:
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-spec-api</artifactId>
   <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Comment: Try adding the javax.mail dependency in MyLibB in a dependencyManagement section.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work as well :'(

Comment: Based on this https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly it seems like it's because of automatic dependencies. Let me try creating the file and see if it works.

Comment: can you post your final pom versions? both dependency and dependencyManagement sections.

Comment: I gave up trying to exclude the System Dependencies (dependencies that are added to the module automatically by the container, including the Java EE api's) and manually downloaded the latest mail jar and placed it inside the `wildfly10/modules/system/layers/base/javax/mail/api/main` folder, and changed filename inside the `module.xml` to the latest mail jar I am now referencing, and deleted the older jar. If I understood correctly (correct me if I am wrong) or at least how I am using it, maven is on a 'Local Resource' level, so under the class loading precedence it would not be loaded first.